# Wpf Custom Textbox Event Handler not working

Tags: wpf

I have created an event handler for all the textboxes like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="TextBox_LostFocus" />
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
    </Style>
```

Now I have created a custom control which extends textbox. But the handlers don't fire for these custom textboxes. Creating separate event setters for this custom textbox also doesnt works

Comment: Is the style applied to your custom type , Usually it's come to place a metadata override to  the style dp in a static ctor in your derived custom control, this would explain why your handlers are not applied.

post your control implementation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `Style` is used without a `x:Key` property, it will apply strictly on `TextBox` elements. You have to either set your `CustomTextBox` as `TargetType` or you could use the `BasedOn` property like so:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="TextBox_LostFocus" />
    <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TextBox_GotFocus"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type my:CustomTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
</Style>
```